# LM1875 bridged amplifier at 12v?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, audio, integrated-circuit, watts

I am trying to build 5-10W amplifier.  The minimum voltage for LM1875 is 16v but 12v is not far from it.  Where I am getting lost is whether I am going to get at least 5W when the amplifiers are bridged together.  I am trying to run it from a 12v battery so there is only +12v and 0v (ground)

Schematic for not bridged amp:
(most of them need +V and -V with ground.. so I'm not sure whether this would work either (+12 and 0v))
[image]

Power output/voltage:

[image]

DATASHEET:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas524a/snas524a.pdf

Comment: Find one that works on your actual available voltage...

Comment: That is what I have. I want to learn and I am willing to work with what I have instead of ordering new parts. If I wanted quick solutions I would just buy a 5w amplifier for a few bucks.

Comment: Then your best bet is to add a second 12V battery.

Comment: Doesn't look like a bridged amplifier to me. Could be used with another one and some circuitry to get there. Are you planning on using two of these?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to bridge them

Comment: The spec's don't specify a minimum voltage. They include curves that go down to \$\pm 15\:\textrm{V}\$. But the schematic I see on page 6 looks to me like it will work on \$\pm 12\:\textrm{V}\$. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: just google 12V bridged amplifier circuit - lots to choose from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use these devices, you really need to look at the schematic on page 6 of the datasheet. The datasheet doesn't actually specify a minimum rail voltage, but it makes extensive use of the kinds of sections which tend to work reasonably well with variations in supply voltage. It should, because the device actually shows it operating with a wide range of supplies, anyway. So the design is pretty solid from what I can see.

Looking at the schematic, I believe it requires about \$3\:\textrm{V}\$ of headroom towards the rails on each side. So with \$\pm 12\:\textrm{V}\$ supply rails, you can't expect any better than \$\pm 9\:\textrm{V}\$ peaks at the output.

The peak voltage required into a load will be \$V_{PK}=\sqrt{2 P R}\$, single-ended (not bridged.) This just happens to work out to about \$\pm 9\:\textrm{V}\$ for \$5\:\textrm{W}\$ into an \$8\:\Omega\$ load. So you might get what you want with just one of these. Perhaps a little less, as my \$3\:\textrm{V}\$ headroom estimate is pretty rough. But bridged, you should have no problem at all.

I think you should just go for it, if you want to try these in a bridged configuration. Personally? I'd probably just use one and keep it simple and consider it good if I got slightly less power than you mentioned. But if you bridge these, I think you'll have no problems at all running at more than twice the power you said into an \$8\:\Omega\$ load.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you are operating the device outside of what it is specified for in the datasheet, you should not expect it to perform well - or even at all. The schematic that you included is a direct copy of the single-supply "Typical Application" in the datasheet, so you're on the right track, but in the end, you would need to find a source of at least 16V.

I'm not sure what your exact specs are, but you could consider using a device like the [TPA1517](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa1517.pdf), as it looks to be within your output power range and input voltage. There are others to choose from, of course, but I picked one with a more DIY-friendly package (this one's PDIP).

Disclaimer: I work for TI, but this just my opinion/suggestion and isn't an official position.